# How to set screen rotation in android for only one activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, screen-rotation

If i set rotation for the inner activity the whole screen rotates. I only want the inner activity to turn into landscape mode, not the outer activity.

This is a screenshot in which you can see 2 activities. One is the whole screen another is the camera that scans a QR code:

[image]

Comment: setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

Comment: add this in your activity onCreate();

Answer (score 1):

Add the below mentioned attribute in your Activity tag inside *AndroidManifest.xml*

> android:screenOrientation="landscape"

Ex:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```